# Why is this clementine/mandarin tree so small and why has it stopped growing?

Tags: trees, fruit-trees, tree-care, growth, fruits

I planted a clementine or mandarin tree from seed maybe two or three years ago. I don't think it has grown much over the last couple of years. See photo (with a sticky note for scale). It doesn't grow, but it also stays alive. I planted another one around the same time that, although not huge itself, it much bigger than this one (see other photo—any advice for this one is also appreciated). I live in the Atlanta area and recently put the tree outside. What can I try to get it to get bigger?

[image]

Second tree for reference:

[image]

Comment: Does it have little bugs on the leaves underside? Use a magnifying glass and see if you have little spider like creatures.

Comment: Does the pot have drainage? Can the water freely run out? It looks like it's sitting flat on a plate which many not allow the water to drain.

Comment: @user33232 I don't spot any spider-like creatures, at least with my bare eyes.

Comment: @Tim Nevins, yes, the pot has drainage. Similar to https://www.ebay.com/itm/10-in-Lime-Green-Plastic-Planter-Pot-Drainage-Hole-Saucer-Indoor-Outdoor-Garden-/132474427805. And I poured lots of water, and it quickly started draining.